# Задать область заполнения background

Tags: css

У свойства background отсутствует возможность заполнять определенное количество пикселей.
Какие способы используются, чтобы заполнить желаемую область, кроме добавления дочерних div элементов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[background-size](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size) и
[background-position](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position)